# Equal Length Group

Tags: r

I am trying to create equal length groups.

```
x <- data.frame(categories = c(27, 100:1000), categories2 = c(27, 100:1000)/1000, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here I am creating 5 groups of equal length.

```
seq(min(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE))/5)
```

It returns this output -

```
[1]   27.0  221.6  416.2  610.8  805.4 1000.0
```

I want the following output -

```
[1]   0  200  400  600  800 1000
```

Similarly for variable **categories2** I want -

```
[1]   0  0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8 1
```

**Update**
This works for first variable, but not work for values less than 1

```
round(seq(min(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE))/5),-2)
```

Comment: Both `round(#, digits =-2)` as well as `round_any(#, 100)` from the plyr package will give you the desired result for the first variable. I do not really understand your question for the second variable, that seems to be the first variable divided by 1000. What exactly is it you want that dividing by 1000 doesn't work?

Comment: Refer ' for second variable I want -'

Comment: For me it had been clearer if you simply specified the variable itself (stating, for categories2 I want -). I really had to read it quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to use `round_any` from the plyr package.

First you put you code `round_any(#, 100)`, which gives you the results for the first variable. For the second you want to use `round_any(#, 0.1)`.

If I replace the # with your syntax it would be:

`round_any(seq(min(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories, na.rm = TRUE))/5), 100)`

and

`round_any(seq(min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE))/5), .1)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use without any package -

```
round(seq(min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE))/5)/0.1, 0.1)*0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, when you type a function you can do F1 to see the details.

Doing so with 'round' tells you you can choose the amount of digits you want with "digits = x"

so, for first you specified '-2', for the second, you just specify '1':

```
round(seq(min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE))/5),  digits = 1)
```

or shorten to :

```
round(seq(min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE), (max(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x$categories2, na.rm = TRUE))/5), 1)
```

also, it wasn't in your question, but you could use the 'length.out' parameter instead of the 'by' one to shorten your line :

```
round(seq(min(x$categories2), max(x$categories2), length.out=5), 1)
```